# Parsing form with HTML Agility Pack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to extract all input elements from a form. When I parse the following form:

```
<form>
<input name='test1' type='text'>
<input name='test2' type='text'>
<input name='test3' type='text'>
</form>
```

everything worked perfectly, HTML Agility Pack was able to detect the input elements in the form but if it has a div parent node like the following, it will not be detected.

```
<form>
<div><input name='test1' type='text'></div>
<div><input name='test2' type='text'></div>
<div><input name='test3' type='text'></div>
</form>
```

I'm using the following code

```
HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("form");

foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node in postForm.Elements("input"))
{
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlAttribute valueAttribute = node.Attributes["value"];
}
```

Can anyone tell me what went wrong? Thanks

Comment: What is postForm here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`HtmlNode.Elements` method gets matching first generation child nodes matching name. After you  put your inputs inside a `<div>` tag they become the second generation child nodes for the form element.

To make your code work use `HtmlNode.Descendants` method which gets all descendant nodes with matching name:

```
foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node in postForm.Descendants("input"))
{
   HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlAttribute valueAttribute = node.Attributes["value"];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't remember what does "`.Elements()`" do, but I assume that it just returns the children nodes... and in your case the direct childs of your Form are `divs`.

You can use XPATH to have a little more control:

```
.SelectNodes("//form/div/input")
```

This will return a list of input nodes in a form, knowing that the input is withing a div tag.

Here you can see an [**XPATH TUTORIAL**](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/) with examples.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Descendants()` instead of `Elements()` - the later only works on direct children but your input elements are nested within divs:

```
 foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node in postForm.Descendants("input"))
 {
     HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlAttribute valueAttribute = node.Attributes["value"];
 }
```